# How to connect SQLPlus with tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, tnsnames

I want to connect with my Oracle database **without** installing Oracle Client.

I downloaded:

- "Instant Client Package - Basic" and
- "Instant Client Package - SQL*Plus"

Then I created folder on `C:\Oracle\instantclient`, where I extracted all packages.

I have been set `system environment` like:

`Path - C:\Oracle\instantclient
NSL_LANG - with properly key
ORACLE_HOME - C:\Oracle\instantclient
ORACLE_SID - C:\Oracle\instantclient
TNS_ADMIN - C:\Oracle\instantclient`

Then I created `tnsnames.ora` file with configuration in `C:\Oracle\instantclient`

and when I puted a command to cmd:

`sqlplus user/password @HOST`

I have a message like:

`ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`

but when I tried like:

`sqlplus user/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=address to host)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=address to SID)))`

everything works properly. Why SQL have a problem with recognize tnsnames.ora file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your command should be:

```
sqlplus user/password@HOST
```

with no space between the password and `@HOST` part.

With the space it treats the `@HOST` as a script to execute once you've logged in, and it tries to connect locally, which produced that TNS error. (As you don't log in the `HOST` isn't ever evaluated to establish if it exists, so it's effectively noise at this point).

```
C:\>sqlplus -l -s x/y @HOST
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

With the space removed it looks for `HOST` as a TNS alias:

```
C:\>sqlplus -l -s x/y@HOST
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

For me that still gets an error since I don't have `HOST` in my `tnsnames.ora`, but it's a different error and you can see it's at least trying to use it as a TNS alias. If you have it defined properly it will be able to connect to your database.

Comment: OMG, you have right! What a stupid mistake :/
Now is working properly. Thank you so much Alex.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER edit $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsname.ora manually, use "netmr" to create Local Name. 
Don't know why it's same but do not work.

Answer (score 0):

This commando works fine for me:

sqlplus /nolog
connect username/password@hostname:port/SERVICENAME